# Is it possible to see if two cells contain similar text in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, string

I've got two columns populated with names, and I want to see if the names in each row are similar (not the exact same, just similar) to each other. Is there any way to do this on Excel?

Comment: Not an Excel implementation, but worth learning about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: And here's the Excel/VBA implementation for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243036/levenshtein-distance-in-excel

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for this.  I would load each column as separate "tables", and it will return the best match (or matches), along with confidence and similarity scores.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can be done using any of the lookup functions.  The trick is to use true instead of false in the lookup parameters.  True delivers approximate matches while false will deliver an exact match.  Hope this helps and have fun!

Comment: That's only true if the first column of the table is _sorted numeric_ data.  It does not create the fuzzy logic using names.